# npmでlocalにあるネストされたパッケージをインストールできない

Tags: npm

以下のような構築のrootで`npm install`を行おうとしています。

```
root
moduleA
moduleB
```

```js
// root\package.json
...
"devDependencies": {
  "moduleA": "file:../moduleA",
  "moduleB": "file:../moduleB"
}
```

```js
// moduleA\package.json
...
"dependencies": {
  "deep-equal": "^1.0.1"  // この deep-equal はほかのどの package でも変わりありません
}
```

```js
// moduleB\package.json
"dependencies": {
  "moduleA": "file:../moduleA"
}
```

結果、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
PS C:\[...]\root> npm i
npm WARN rollback Rolling back deep-equal@1.0.1 failed (this is probably harmless): C:\Users\180245\nestedCheck\moduleA\node_modules\deep-equal is not a child of C:\Users\180245\nestedCheck\root
npm WARN root@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! path C:\Users\180245\nestedCheck\root\node_modules\.staging\deep-equal-91c42369
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\[...]\root\node_modules\.staging\deep-equal-91c42369' -> 'C:\Users\[...]\moduleA\node_modules\deep-equal'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\[...]\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-09T05_51_30_168Z-debug.log
```

求める動作としては、root以下で`npm install`を行って正常に終了することです。

なぜこのようなエラーが発生するのかが不明です。教えていただけませんでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。